# Stopping a lemonade demo after completion

Tags: javascript, media-player

I have embedded a demo created by a training material platform called Launchfire. The demo game is embedded In our live site. I need it to close when the trainees have completed the training demo. Here is the script. 
function

```
Function29(){  
$('#player').empty();
 Lemonade.DemoPlayer.play({
        demo: '750e8759-6fa1-45be-                               
 aa8a-03f02cbe45af',
        container: $('#player'),
        locale: 'en_US',
        finishButtonText:'Continue',
        horizontalPadding: 25,
        onFinish: function() {
$("#player").html(
              "Click anywhere to continue"
            );
            // you can do anything   when the game ends!
        },
        onStepChange: function     (previousStep, currentStep,    currentHotspot, totalSteps) {
            // every time the scene changes, this event is called
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Lee - what do you mean by "close it when it is completed". It's just be populating a #player div.  Are you trying to get back onto a new page?

Comment: Yes, after clicking the final "continue" Button you have to click an X in the top right hand corner of the frame. I would like it to close on its own once the button is clicked.

Comment: So the golden question is - what does "close" mean.  Do you want it to go back to another page? Do you want a div to disappear?  Can you reproduce this on a codepen.io build?

Comment: I would like it to redirect to the page it started from.

Comment: Can we define what finishButtonText: executes? Like when the continue button is clicked, remove the player?

Comment: I think that this is precisely what onFinish does.  You could just make it do `onFinish: function() { window.location.href = 'http://google.com'; }` instead of layering on a div.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it in codepin